# Archive Old Data in MySQL and organize big data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have to design a MySql database where a table has million of records, and it become bigger every day, my first approach is to use a partition based on year:

example:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(30),
    lname VARCHAR(30),
    hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
    separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
    job_code INT,
    store_id INT
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( YEAR(separated) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1991),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1996),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2001),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

My goals is to archive periodically all data, somewhere, exe. historical tables, or something else, but from frontend application, i need to query the current year data, and the past years data.

Which is the best approach for you to do this? any experiences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Bigger every day" in not a problem.  "Archive periodically" is a good use of `PARTITION BY RANGE`.

On Dec. 31, create the next partition.

Name the partitions according to what they contain (`p1999 VALUES LESS THAN (2000)`, etc).

Use "transportable tablespaces" to do the archiving.  5.6 and 5.7 work differently, so check details.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint